# ODE: Is simple substitution correct?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Quick question.

> Given
>
> $\ddot{y}+\frac{1}{x}\dot{y}-\frac{4}{x^2}y=0$
>
> Solve the ODE by substituting $t=\ln(x)$.

Is my following substitution correct:

$$\ddot{y}(t)+e^{-t}\dot{y}(t)-4e^{-2t}y(t)=0$$

If yes, is it right to assume that I can find the solution by finding the converging power series of the Matrix $A(t)$ of the converted first order system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

Note that we have, through the substitution, $x=e^t \implies \frac{dt}{dx}=\frac{1}{x}$ and $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\dot{y}(t)\frac{dt}{dx} =\dot{y}(t)\frac{1}{x}=e^{-t}\dot{y}(t)$$ $$\implies \frac{1}{x}\frac{dy}{dx}=e^{-2t}\dot{y}(t)$$

Similarly, $$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{dy}{dx})= \frac{d}{dt}(\frac{dy}{dx})\frac{dt}{dx}=\,?$$

Comment: With your hint I finally did it!  Took me a long time but it paid off! Had your response open all day as a guide. Thanks! Will add answer later.

Answer (score 1):

It is a Cauchy Euler equation (especially if it is a homogeneous one ) you may also look for the solutions of the form $y=x^\alpha$, where $\alpha$ is a constant to be determined. Taking the derivatives $y'=\alpha x^{\alpha-1}$ and $y''=\alpha(\alpha-1)x^{\alpha-2}$ and putting these into the equation gives $$(\alpha^2-4)x^{\alpha-2}\Rightarrow \alpha^2-4=0\Rightarrow \alpha=-2,\,\alpha=2\Rightarrow y_1=x^{-2},\,y_2=x^2.$$

Comment: This is also a great comment but the other one was more specific regarding the substitution. Nevertheless, you deserve an upvote!